# Unity build misses "Publish" option in Visual Studio 2022, forcing publish by including Package.appxmanifest generates "Error: APPX1502"

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, il2cpp, appxmanifest

I am making a HoloLens 2 application using Unity 2021.3.28f1 and MRTK 2.8.3.0.

When I build my Unity UWP (IL2CPP) application with the following settings:

[image: unity build settings]

The Visual Studio project that is generated does not recognise the included Package.appxmanifest.
This results in the "Create App Packages..." button missing in the right-click menu and being greyed out under "Project>Publish>Create App Packages...".
When I manually add the Package.appxmanifest, the option returns but the build fails with:

> "error APPX1502: The project contains 2 items that represent the app manifest: Package.appxmanifest, C:\...\Package.appxmanifest. The project can contain only one app manifest. Done building project "project.vcxproj" -- FAILED."

I have tried opening the project.vcxproj file with vscode to check any duplicate mentions of the appxmanifest, I suspected that a duplicate mention could be found in this file but there weren't any duplicates.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what is causing this issue and a potential fix?

Answer (score 0):

It is reported as a bug in Unity forum, there is also a work around mentioned

[Unity forum bug reported link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-version-2021-3-28f1-lacks-the-uwp-publish-button-in-visual-studio-build-for-package-generation.1480761/)

In short dragging and dropping **package.appxmanifest** from Unity Data to UWP project fixes issue as of now.

[image]

Comment: I get the same Error since i added Vuforia (10.19.3) to my Hololens (Unity 2021.3.30f1) project:


`C:\...\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1311,5): error APPX1502: The project contains 2 items that represent the app manifest: Package.appxmanifest, C:\...\WSAPlayer\AugmeNDT\Package.appxmanifest. 
The project can contain only one app manifest. [C:\...\WSAPlayer\AugmeNDT\AugmeNDT.vcxproj]`


How can adding Vuforia yield this error? And is there a Solution?

Comment: This is more related to Visual studio and Unity version installed in PC as far as my understanding. Opening in VS2022 and dragging and dropping Package.appxmanifest file to the UWP module fixes the error for me. Try building to a clean new folder and do this as the solution loads in VS2022.