# Manifest Error during Appx build [Hololens 2, Unity, Vuforia]

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, vuforia, hololens, mrtk

## Short Overview

Unity UWP Application for Hololens 2 using MRTK with later added Vuforia.

- Unity Version: 2021.3.30f1
- MRTK: 2.8.3.0
- Vuforia: 10.19.3

## Problem

I have an application in which I work with the Hololens 2. To test the application on the Hololens, I use the MRTK Build Window - I always use the "Build all, then install" button, which allows me to run the app on the device. This has worked well so far.

Now I want to add tracking and have therefore imported Vuforia into my Unity application. In the Unity play menu, with my webcam, the recognition of image targets works. But when I want to build the application for the Hololens, I now get an error that revolves around the app manifest:

`C:\...\VisualStudio\v17.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1311,5): error APPX1502: The project contains 2 items that represent the app manifest: Package.appxmanifest, C:\...\WSAPlayer\ProjectName\Package.appxmanifest. The project can contain only one app manifest. [C:\...\WSAPlayer\ProjectName\ProjectName.vcxproj]`

This means that the app is not created and no application is installed on the hololens. However, I have not changed the manifest by myself. There is one `Package.appxmanifest` in the Build folder (WSAPlayer) and of course a `manifest.json` file under ProjectName\Packages.

#### What i tried

I tried deleting one of each and both manifest files (Package.appxmanifest, manifest.json) bot then i just get the error that i have no manifest.
I also tried to move package.appxmanifest from Unity Data to IL2CPPOutputProject like described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77201912/13896230), then it creates a AppX file but when i install it on the Hololens (Install AppX) and start it from the device i get a 2D Window of my application (A 2D window with my application floating in the envrionment). Still if i try to do "Build all, then install" afterwards i get the same error - so no temporary solution (if it would have worked).

## Question

Why do i get a error describing a second app manifest after adding Vuforia to my Unity + MRTK project?